# Can I use Cloud formation stack name once it is deleted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, infrastructure-as-code, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I accidently deleted the cloud formation stack, I do not need the reosources, but have a requirements to use the same cloudformation stack name, Can I get back the stack (without resources it's fine) ?

Comment: >>(without resources it's fine) <<  You cannot have a stack without resources.  Why would you want the stack back without resources, what are you using the stack for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Stack names are "reusable".

Each stack deployment is identified by its own unique `Stack ID`. The stack ID lets CloudFormation keep track of the stack history across multiple deployments if the same stack name.

```sh
# a stack id
arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789012:stack/MyStack/737e1e20-a947-11ec-871d-2202e855dcb5
```

When you call the `aws cloudformation list-stacks` API, you get a list of stack deployments by ID, including those with a `DELETE_COMPLETE` status.